# Wpf. Problems using Culture

Tags: c#, wpf, culture

I want to make a multilingual application.

I do this (Binding from UI):

```
private CultureInfo _culture;
public CultureInfo Culture
{
    get { return _culture; }
    set
    {
        if (_culture != value)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanging(() => Culture);
            _culture = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Culture);

            if (CultureManager.UICulture.Name != _culture.Name)
            {
                CultureManager.UICulture = _culture;  // line A
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but on line A, an exception occurs:

> NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

What can it be?

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that the exception is thrown on the line you indicate. More likely, it is thrown at the `if`, because `_culture` is `null`.

You either need to disallow setting the culture to `null` by adding a guard clause:

```
    private CultureInfo _culture;
    public CultureInfo Culture
    {
        get { return _culture; }
        set
        {
            if(value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            if (_culture != value)
            {
                RaisePropertyChanging(() => Culture);
                _culture = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Culture);

                if (CultureManager.UICulture.Name != _culture.Name)
                {
                CultureManager.UICulture = _culture;  // line A
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

Or you can only change the UI culture if a culture has been set:

```
if (_culture != null && CultureManager.UICulture.Name != _culture.Name)
{
    CultureManager.UICulture = _culture;  // line A
}
```

Comment: _culture  is not null. i checked it

Comment: it is from Infralution.Localization.Wpf

Comment: @Zhenia: In that case, you might want to take it to the Infralution support, I guess.